# How the hreflang is supposed to be built?

Tags: php, html, seo, multilingual, rel

My question is does the

```
<link rel="alternate" href="http://example.com/en" hreflang="en">
<link rel="alternate" href="http://example.com/it" hreflang="it">
```

should be like above an all pages or should be changed with the actual url of every page like:

```
<link rel="alternate" href="http://example.com/en/<?=$current;?>" hreflang="en">
<link rel="alternate" href="http://example.com/it/<?=$current;?>" hreflang="it">
<link rel="alternate" href="http://example.com/<?=$current;?>" hreflang="x-default">
```

Comment: [Google](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/189077?hl=en) read Common mistakes -> Example hreflang configuration: Annotations in action.

Answer (score 0):

HTML5 [defines](http://www.w3.org/TR/2014/REC-html5-20141028/links.html#rel-alternate):

> If the `alternate` keyword is used with the `hreflang` attribute, and that attribute's value differs from the root element's language, it indicates that the referenced document is a translation.

So it’s for translated *documents* (i.e., pages), not sites.

`http://example.com/en` links to `http://example.com/it`,
`http://example.com/en/hello` links to `http://example.com/it/ciao`.