# Show country specific website in search

Tags: url, dns, internationalization, seo

We have a website which we want to replicate and put on country specific domain names.

How can we ensure only these country specific domain names show up in searches?

i.e. - ensure that `http://getbunnybox.nl` shows up for Dutch searchers instead of `https://getbunnybox.com`.

Is this possible?

Comment: just a starting  `<meta name="country" content="FR" />`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HTML5 provides the [`alternate` link type](http://www.w3.org/TR/2014/REC-html5-20141028/links.html#rel-alternate) which, together with the `hreflang` attribute, can be used for translations:

> If the `alternate` keyword is used with the `hreflang` attribute, and that attribute's value differs from the root element's language, it indicates that the referenced document is a translation.

The `hreflang` (as well as the `lang`) attribute [takes a **BCP 47 language tag** as value](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/a/74080/17633), which [can have a **region** subtag](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28112813/1591669).

So if you have a document in Dutch and you want to target the Netherlands, you can use the language tag `nl-NL` (and `nl` if the country doesn’t matter, and `nl-BE` if you want to target Dutch speakers in Belgium, etc.).

From [each page](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31291038/1591669) of `getbunnybox.com`, you could link to each corresponding page of `getbunnybox.nl` (and vice versa) with a `link` element:

```html
<!-- on http://getbunnybox.com/hello -->
<link href="http://getbunnybox.nl/hallo" rel="alternate" hreflang="nl-NL" />
```